# Does "さよならだけは言わないで" mean "don't only say goodbye" or "don't say goodbye"?

Tags: translation

One of the famous songs by Mayumi Itsuwa (五輪 真弓) is by the name さよならだけは言わないで  I can't find a good translation of the name on a webpage but Google Translate suggests it means "Do not say only goodbye" and iTunes spells out the song as "Sayonaradakewa Iwanaide" as the pronunciation.  Does the name of this song mean "don't only say goodbye (to me)"?

Answer (score 11):

The last thing I want to do is compete with Google Translate, but "he" is wrong again.

It means "***Say anything but 'good-bye'***."

> 「～～だけは + Verb in negative form」

is a common expression meaning:

> "(Verb) anything but ~~"

「ピーマン**だけは**食{た}べられ**ません**。」 = "I can eat anything but green peppers."

「マリアと**だけは**結婚{けっこん}したく**ない**。」 = "I would marry anybody but Maria."

Because this is such a useful expression, I will close by saying:

> 「この表現{ひょうげん}**だけは**忘{わす}れ**ない**でください！」 = "Forget anything but this expression, please!"

Comment: I suppose "Say anything but goodbye" means "Say anything except goodbye"... rather than "Say anything, but goodbye (to you) anyways"

Comment: It seems to be the difference between **だけは** and **だけ**, right?

Comment: @user3169 you mean you don't understand what it means "Say anything, but goodbye (to you) anyways" ?  that means, "hey, you can saying anything (to explain), but goodbye (anyways, because I never want to see you again)."

Comment: @user3169 Yes, 「さよならだけ言わないで」 or 「さよならだけを言わないで」 would mean "Don't only say goodbye" (i.e. "Say something along with goodbye").

Comment: @太極者無極而生 No, I agree with your first comment. Sorry for making a confusion.

Comment: I googled for `だけは` and it seems like it means `only`?  So I suppose `だけは + a verb in negative form` can be literally translated to, for example, "Say anything, **only do not** say goodbye."?