# Meaning of だけはわからない

Tags: translation, usage, nuances

> それでも彼には、自分のこと**だけはわからない**。

I'm translating the above sentence from Japanese to English, and I'm having issues with understanding what **だけはわからない** means.

[Why does だけ come before は?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45184/why-does-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91-come-before-%E3%81%AF)
says that だけは means 'at least'; and [https://jisho.org/search/だけは](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AF) supports this with a definition of 'at least not (when followed by a negative)'. I know that わからない means 'to not understand' as its わかる in the negative form. When I tried to translate the above, the resulting sentence made barely any sense (Example 1) or it failed to convey the 'abstracting focusing' aspect of [のこと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-in-sentences-such-as-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A0/2216#2216) (Example 2).

Example:

> 1) Even so, he understands anything but not what is only about himself.
>
> 2) Still, he at least doesn’t understand himself.

What do I need to know in order to properly understand what **だけはわからない** means in the above sentence?

Comment: は is still functioning as a contrast particle here. It can still mean "just" or "at least" depending on the context. See definition 1 of https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/136029/meaning/m0u/ to see why it can mean the latter. My tentative understanding of the line is that if there's one thing he doesn't understand, it's himself.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25831/9831

Comment: @user26484 I unfortunately will have to translate the dictionary to understand any of it. My understanding is that the には is acting as a contrast particle, but the は in だけは is something else. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the second は?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 「～～だけ + は + Verb + ない」

is the pattern you will need to learn as it is commonly used. **It is an expression that describes the single or very few exceptions to a phenomenon**.  It means:

> "Someone [Verb] everything but/except ~~."

Thus,

> 「それでも彼には、自分のことだけはわからない。」

means:

> "He, however, knows/understands everything but about himself."

or

> "Things about himself are the only thing he does not understand."

To give you an actual example of the most commonly-used phrases in the real Japanese-speaking world, you will hear something like:

- 「野菜{やさい}は大好{だいす}き。でも、ピーマンだけは食{た}べられないのよね。」

That means "I love vegetables.  I eat all kinds except for the bell pepper."

- 「お前{まえ}だけはわからん！」 said jokingly most of the time

This means "I understand a lot of people but you!" This is said when the other person has been acting strange.

It ***does not*** mean "Only you don't understand (something)." or "You are the only person who doesn't understand (something)."

Comment: Is there a name for the pattern that I can google to do further self-study, or a site that you would recommend?

Comment: I understand that のこと can be used to abstract or provide focus on a subject or person, as stated here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-こと-in-sentences-such-as-あなたのことが好きだ/2216#2216 
 abstracting": (2)(ア) ある物事に関連する事柄。 Things related to a particular thing.
"focusing": (2)(イ) ある人物が動作・心情の対象であることを示す。 Indicates a person is the object of an action/emotion.

I tried to use "only" to provide the "abstract" on what he doesn't understand, like you did in your translation. I'm aware that ～～だけ + は + Verb + ない does not mean "...only...". But thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

You are over analyzing this sentence. だけは is not a special kind of grammatical construct. だけ is just a part of the topic of this sentence. The sentence then moves on to saying that the person in question doesn't understand this topic. In this case (*only*) themselves.

***Source:***

> それでも彼には、自分のことだけはわからない。

***Translation (gist):***

Even so (*comparing to something*), he could understand everything but he could not understand himself.

***Break down:***

それでも彼には => Despite (*this*),

自分のことだけ => It is only the topic of himself

は => (*highlights the previous segment as the topic of interest*)

わからない => That (*he*) could not understand.